# Sonicwall Block all internet traffic but email

Tags: email, firewall, sonicwall, pop3

I set up a sonicwall to block internet to users on a certain switch port. Works well, but now they want to access email, while still blocking the internet. I can't figure out a way to do this using Sonicwall without buying the Content Filtering Service. They just use pop3, so I'm not aware of any sort of onsite pop3 bypass I could set up internally?

Comment: Create an outbound rule for POP. What's Content Filtering got to do with it? I don't understand the dilemma.

Comment: Sorry, momentary brain-dead day apparently. Not sure why this escaped my understanding so much.

Comment: It happens to all of us. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the Content Filter Services (which, by the way, serves a different scope: *it selectively block some web categories*, all running on the standard HTTP port).

You simply need to configure a LAN to WAN rules enabling DNS and POP3 for the selected IP/users, while blocking all other traffic.

Comment: Perfect, someone else had this exact same suggestions. I'll need to configure SMTP too I'm assuming?

Comment: It really depends on what you need. If you want to enable emailing _and_ your mail server is external to your network, you likely need to enable POP3, POP3S, SMTP, SMTPS, IMAP, IMAPS and DNS.